# Activity Manager can't find my Service - why?

Tags: android, android-service, activity-manager

I have a service which returns `START_STICKY` on `#onStartCommand()` and it is being started in my `MainActivity's` `#onCreate()` method. When i close my app, `Service` is being destroyed and it starts itself again. However, when it starts itself, `ActivityManager` can't find it. So there are 2 instance of my service running..

I use this code to check is service dead, it returns true everytime even if it lives after service starts itself.

```
public static boolean isServiceDead(Context context) {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : am.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(LockerService.class.getName()))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what are you doing in your activity on destroy ? i mean "When i stop my Activity" ?

Comment: I'm doing nothing on destroy. When I close the app, service is being destroyed and creates itself again because of START_STICKY @Quicklearner edited question.

Comment: which device are you using for testing ?

Comment: Android Emulator API 27 @Quicklearner

Comment: please test it on real device , stock android and Customized OS devices and check the behaviour

Comment: its same on nexus 5 @Quicklearner

Comment: In your `isServiceDead()` method, add some debug logging in the `for` loop and output the value that `getClassName()` returns for each `Service` it finds. That may help you find the problem.

Comment: Yes, i have tried it. When I start service with startService() command, for loop prints my service, but after it destrorys and starts itself, for loop prints nothing @DavidWasser

Comment: How do you know your Servicecis restarted? Do you know for sure your Service is running? Hiw?

Comment: I'm logging in onCreate method, it's being created @DavidWasser

Comment: Just being created does not mean it is running. `onStartCommand()` must be called and depending on the return value it will either be running or not.

Comment: You call also use `adb shell dumpsys activity services` to get more information about running `Services`.